# rails/ActiveRecord: How can I specify a different class for a particular attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In rails 3, I have a database model that has a `birthday` field, of type `date`.  For various reasons (e.g. a date without a known year), I'd like to have this be of a class other than `Date`, and/or to mix something in to the `Date` class for *only objects created from this attribute*.  What's the best way to go about this?

For example, suppose I want to do something like:

```
class BirthDate < Date
  def to_s
    case year
    when 1 # if I store a date with a null year, it sets it to 1
      strftime("%m/%d")
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

That class does get me the behavior I want (for the moment; it's entirely possible I'll modify it in future), and I can get my model to give me access to this using something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bday
    BirthDate.new(birthday.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
  end
end
```

And then just change my views to use bday instead of birthday.  This seems kind of wasteful, though (having to create a new object from one already created -- never mind that `Date` doesn't seem to have a "copy constructor" type thing?  (Or am I just missing it somewhere?)

Anyway, I would think that perhaps ActiveRecord might provide something that might look like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  class_for :birthday => BirthDate
end
```

Is there anything like that?  I've done a bunch of google searches, and looked through a number of docs, and haven't found it.  But since I don't know what it might be called,

(Perhaps it's time to start digging through the source -- I've heard that's a good way to learn more about a platform.  Then again, [some say otherwise](http://scientificninja.com/blog/dont-read-source-code) ;))

Comment: Why not use a mixin on your Person class, replacing your 'birthday' accessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the getter for the attribute manually:

```
def birthday
  BirthDate.parse(birthday_before_type_cast)
end
```

Comment: That seems to work for what I'm doing, thanks!  I do have one follow-up question, though: (1) Is this any different/better/worse/whatever than `BirthDate.parse(read_attribute(:birthday))`?  [Side-note: I finally looked this up in the source; it's in `lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb`, and there's nothing like my `class_for` idea represented.]

Comment: read_attribute method actually type_casts the attribute..so the date object will be initialized..but birthday_before_type_cast will give date field as it is in the database..see [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-5B-5D)